# Extracting column names for each csv file and append it into 1 csv

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I am trying to only extract the column names for each CSV file and then append into one CSV showing only the column name and filenames. Below is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob2

# use glob to get all the csv files
# in the folder
path = r'G:\serv_agr\Alberta_Billing\MM1077-NewHorizonMall\Meters\Gas_Wtr'
csv_files = glob2.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:

    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f)

    # print the location and filename
    file_name = f.split("\\")[-1]
    print('File Name Original:', file_name)

    # print the content
    print('Columns:', df.columns)

    columns = df.columns
```

This helps print each column name but import it into one csv.

This is what the output should look like:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | File Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Time | CSV1 |
| Dates | Time2 | csv2 |

Comment: A concrete example of a file or two and the desired output would help

Comment: Number of columns are fixed!

Output would look like :

Column name 1 | Column name 2 | Column name 3  | Filename
       Date                     time                      unit                   csv1
       Date                     Time                     uNit                   csv2

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of reading the whole file it's better to read only the first line:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from glob import glob
from os import path

data_folder = "."
headers = []
files = []

for f in glob(path.join(data_folder, "*.csv")):
    files.append(path.basename(f))
    with open(f) as f:
        headers.append(next(csv.reader(f)))

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(headers)
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Column {x + 1}')
    .assign(**{'File name': files})
)
```

The line `pd.DataFrame(headers)` works even if `headers` is a *jagged* list (i.e. files have different number of headers). In case if there are some empty lines in front of headers, we have to rewrite the for-loop to skip them:

```
    ...
    with open(f) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        while not (line:=next(r)):
            pass   # empty lines result in empty lists
        headers.append(line)
    ...
```